# Xlsio Excel file as Mailkit attachement

Tags: c#, .net-core, byte, syncfusion, mailkit

I'm using Mailkit to send email, and I would like to send a created Excel file (thanks to Xlsio) as an Email attachement.

I achieved to send the email, I see the attachement with good extension (.xlsx) but when I want to open it I have an error "Format or extention is not valid".

This is what I've coded for creating the Excel file

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
               
workbook.SaveAs(stream, ExcelSaveType.SaveAsXLS);
           
FileAttachementDto file = new()
{                    
      FileName = fileName,
      File = stream,      // Type of File property is Stream              
};
```

What I'v coded for adding the file to the email attachements

```
var attachements = MimeEntity.Load(
            new ContentType("application", "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"),
            new MemoryStream(myFile.File.ReadAsBytes()));       

bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add(attachements);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
var attachements = MimeEntity.Load(
        new ContentType("application", "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"),
        new MemoryStream(myFile.File.ReadAsBytes()));
```

That is for parsing HTTP web responses.

Just do this instead:

```
var attachment = new MimePart ("application", "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") {
    FileName = "fileName.xls",
    ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64,
    Content = new MimeContent (new MemoryStream (myFile.File.ReadAsBytes ()))
};
```

Comment: I don't have error anymore, but now I have a lot of unreadable characters in the opened file

Comment: Have you verified that the file output generated by Xlsio works correctly? If so, then you must have some code in your program that corrupts the data (e.g. by treating the content as text)

Comment: I had to save the file on disk to make it work

Answer (score 1):

We suggest you to set the workbook version as Xlsx before saving the Excel document and remove the ExcelSaveType.SaveAsXLS parameter in SaveAs method of IWorkbook.

Code Snippet:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);    
workbook.Version = ExcelVersion.Xlsx;
workbook.SaveAs(stream);          

FileAttachementDto file = new()    
{
      FileName = fileName,    
      File = stream,      // Type of File property is Stream  
};
```

​​​